# Add a public ssh key to the authorized_keys of a user

Tags: ssh

I have to work on an issue happening on a server running Arch Linux. The other dev sent me an e-mail with the key to access as the root user and wrote me this "You should login as root, upload your public ssh key and add it to the authorized_keys of the xxx user".

He created a user to run a node application. I have the public key file and I need to add it to the `authorized_keys` of the user he uses to run the app, so I can ssh as this user.

My problem is that I don't know the command to do it. I would like to know how to do it with a file in my local machine or just copy the authorized_keys from the root.

Comment: Open up `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` in an editor and append the SSH key there. There are plenty of tutorials around the internet for this kind of thing, please check those out before asking here.

Comment: `ssh-copy-id` is part of every single ssh package I've found and I'm not willing to bet that PuTTY doesn't have an equivalent.

Comment: ssh-copy-id -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub user@server-address

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Send your key to `/tmp` then append it to `authorized_keys`.
Replace `SERVER` and `USER` in these commands:

```bash
scp ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub root@SERVER:/tmp/id_andre_luiz
ssh root@SERVER
cat /tmp/id_andre_luiz >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

Be careful to use the `>>` (and not just a single `>`) in order to append to the `authorized_keys` file instead of overwriting it.

Comment: Accept this one if for some reason the user in question does not have even a restricted shell access.

Comment: Without transferring the key separately with `scp`: `ssh user@remote 'cat >>.ssh/authorized_keys' <local_public_key_file`

Answer (score 5):

I do it like this:

```
cat <your_public_key_file> >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

Note the double > without the double > the existing contents of authorized_keys will be over-written (nuked!) and that may not be desirable.

Answer (score 3):

The helper program `ssh-copy-id` does exactly what you ask, and as a happy benefit, will also create and secure both the `~/.ssh/` directory and the `authorized_keys` file if they don't exist, or simply append the key to the existing file if they do.

Even better, it will check whether that key already exists, and protect you from duplicates:

```
shadur@periapsis:~$ ssh-copy-id -i .ssh/id_ed25519.pub luminosity
/usr/bin/ssh-copy-id: INFO: Source of key(s) to be installed: ".ssh/id_ed25519.pub"
/usr/bin/ssh-copy-id: INFO: attempting to log in with the new key(s), to filter out any that are already installed

/usr/bin/ssh-copy-id: WARNING: All keys were skipped because they already exist on the remote system.
        (if you think this is a mistake, you may want to use -f option)
```

This helper program will work from any place that can reach the target system with ssh and has the public key you want to add available, which is effectively anywhere that you'd want to do this from.

Comment: This is obviously the best answer for most cases.  In my case, however, I want to propagate user public keys that are checked in to our source control to several servers, using a script that an admin (who already has access) will run.  `ssh-copy-id` with the `-i` flag depends on both parts of the key pair being copied, so not usable in my (edge) case.

Comment: In that case I recommend Ansible and the `authorized_keys` ansible module.