# SSH to user other than root

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, key-authentication

I can use `ssh -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa root@SERVER` to connect to my Ubuntu VM but I have another user in same VM and I would like to connect directly to it. I tried `ssh -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa newuser@SERVER` but I get this error:  `Permission denied (publickey)`

Comment: Does the other user have the correct public key in their `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` file?

Comment: @Kusalananda it was empty, I added the public key to it and it working fine now, Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is likely that the non-root user on the server does not have a `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` file, or that it does not contain the correct public SSH key.  Copying the correct public SSH key to that file should make the login over SSH work.

Related: [Add a public ssh key to the authorized_keys of a user](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/471837/add-a-public-ssh-key-to-the-authorized-keys-of-a-user)